# Simple search functionality in Meteor using form input

Tags: meteor, spacebars

So I'm trying to implement a very simple search functionality in my Meteor app. It's a very simple medical dictionary app, so I have only one collection which contains all the terms along with their respective definitions, pronunciations, etc. My goal is for a user to input their search query using a form input, and display the relevant search results (after hitting submit, after keyup or keydown events, doesn't really matter for now; this is just a prototype). Here's what I have so far.

**Search Bar** *(part of a template called `header.html`)*

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Event Handler** *(called `header.js`)*

```
Template.header.events({
'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = $(e.target).find('[name=search]').val();

    // Log the query for testing
    console.log(query);

    //Log the object that is returned for testing
    console.log(Dictionary.find({english: query}).fetch());

    var result = Dictionary.find({english: query}).fetch();

  }
});
```

**List of Results** *(This is the part that doesn't work, in a template called `itemsList.html`)*

```
<template name="itemsList">
  <div class="items">
    {{#each dictionary}}
      <ul>
        <!-- itemPage just refers to the page individual items -->
        <li><a href="{{pathFor 'itemPage'}}">{{english}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

In this case `{{english}}` refers to the piece of data in the collection I would like to search for (the english word in the collection `Dictionary`).

So, now that I've got all that out of the way, my question is: what do I do from here? In `header.js`, the result from `console.log(Dictionary.find({english: query}).fetch());` is/are the *object(s)* I'm looking for, so basically, what must I do to send that object/those objects to my `itemsList.html` template so I can iterate over it with a cursor?

I think I've been working at this too long, because I'm sure the solution is something really simple. Any help is appreciated, and if my approach is all wrong (I've seen a lot of people using sessions when searching for things), please let me know what I should do better. Also, I'm using iron-router and have autopublish turned off, so if changes need to made to either of those things please let me know that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just save your search string in a session and subscribe using the session as an argument if it exists, that way you can dynamically subscribe to the data that you need to populate your template